# Animate a menuhover with recognizing where the active link is

Tags: jquery, menu, jquery-animate, mouseover, mouseout

Soo, I have this script: [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Autodealers/q2AVN/)

As you can see it animates when hovering menu items, but when the li breaks, the active div will ignore that and decides to fly away.

I recommend to visit my link for understanding my question better. Any ideas of how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!
With kind regards,
Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The animation finds the index  of the position of the li hovered (e.g. index = 5 if it's the 5th `li`), and simply calculates the left-margin of an absolutely positioned element as that many times the width of the hovered item. The animation does nothing to take float dropping into account, including the vertical positioning.

Rather than this, Animate the left and top properties of the absolutely positioned element to become the same as the hovered item.

I've done this here:
http://jsfiddle.net/q2AVN/7/

Comment: Taking my words back. That's indeed a great solution. +1.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Faust! This is exactly what I want :-) Cheers. +1

Answer (score 1):

One possible idea is to make menu items not to break. Otherwise it will be hard to rewrite the animation.

In order to do that you can use CSS style `white-space: nowrap` applied to the parent element (i.e. `ul` or `div`) and setting style `display: inline-block` (instead of `float: left`) to `li` elements.

Comment: booom @VisioN just to back up your answer bruv :) http://jsfiddle.net/Rfn3E/ have a nice one :) cheerios! (Oh and +1 bruv)

Comment: The animation is not hard. See my answer.

Comment: Ty for the reply, but I can't define my width when using the white-space: nowrap. [See my edit](http://jsfiddle.net/Autodealers/q2AVN/8/)

Comment: I think the @Faust solution is really nice then.